# writing conditions inside 'If' when using 'Plot' or 'Plot3D' etc

Tags: plotting, conditional

How to write condition inside `If` when condition spans a chunk of code (like a Module) rather than a single liner or with `;`

Example:

Output from

```
aa = 0;
ff = x^2 + y^2;
If[aa == 0,
 Plot3D[ff, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
   ff /. {x -> 1, y -> 1},
 Print["If condition fails"]]
```

[image: Output:]

is different from the Output if only 'true' condition in above code is executed without `If`

```
Plot3D[ff, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
ff /. {x -> 1, y -> 1}
```

[image: Output]

If we use semicolon after every statement in the condition, then the code looks like its being executed sequentially as mentioned below

```
If[aa == 0,
 Print["Inside true condition"];
 Print[ff];
 ff = ff + 2;
 Print[ff],
 Print["If condition fails"]]
```

But this defeats the purpose of using `Plot` as `;` suppresses output

So how can we get same behavior even when using `If` ?

*extended*:

Why does idendation of each line inside each condition of `If` change automatically depending on ,if I add `;` ?

Comment: An 'If' statement will return one thing.  I'm your first code, it is the product of the plot and `ff`.  You could have it return a `List` with both the plot and `ff`

Comment: I got what you mentioned , but like other languages how can we make the conditions execute one by one. As `If` returns one thing it doesn't serve my purpose ... I want all conditions be executed. Is there a `Mathematica` way of doing this.

Comment: Re *extended*: If you omit the `;`, then you're **multiplying** the lines inside `If`, and *Mathematica* formats [`Times[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Times.html) differently than [`ConditionalExpression[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConditionalExpression.html). Whether WRI intended it or not, this helps one see whether one has accidentally omitted a semicolon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for [`CellPrint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellPrint.html) and [`ExpressionCell`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExpressionCell.html).  The only difference with multiline input cells is that the output cell is not label with an `Out[..]` label.

```
aa = 0;
ff = x^2 + y^2;
If[aa == 0,
 CellPrint@ ExpressionCell[
   Plot3D[ff, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}],
   "Output"];
 ff /. {x -> 1, y -> 1},
 Print["If condition fails"]]
```

[image]

You can fake an `Out[]` label by adding this option to `ExpressionCell`:

```
CellLabel -> "Out[" <> ToString@$Line <> "]="
```

It's a bit misleading since the output is not actually saved in `Out[$Line]`.  Or you could your own custom label.

Comment: This so much close to what I was looking, another small query ... If I have multiple `Plot3D` or similar functions, do I need to code  `CellPrint` and `ExpressionCell` for all plots in that condition? (it would be dull if I repeat the same 5-6 times)

Comment: @rainversion_3 Yes, if you want each in its own cell.  There's also `GraphicsGrid[]` & relatives for arranging them in a grid in a single cell. One also could use a loop or `Map`: `CellPrint@ExpressionCell[#, "Output"] & /@ {plot1, plot2, ...}`. You could also set the option `DisplayFunction -> (CellPrint@ExpressionCell[#, "Output"] &)` or maybe `DisplayFunction -> ((CellPrint@ExpressionCell[#, "Output"]; #) &)` with `SetOptions[Plot3D, (* opts *)]`.  But that would cause all `Plot3D` to be printed when they are computed.

Comment: @rainversion_3 You can also abbreviate the process with your own function: `printOut[g_] := CellPrint@ExpressionCell[g, "Output"];` and then simply write `printOut[plot1]`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The desired behavior can be obtained with

```
If[aa == 0, Column[{Plot3D[ff, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, ImageSize -> Medium], 
    ff /. {x -> 1, y -> 1}}], Print["If condition fails"]]
```

`Column` displays the outputs of all functions it encloses, and arranges them in a column (as the name suggests).  `ImageSize->Medium` is need to obtain the desired graphics size, which otherwise would be smaller.

[image]

With respect to the last sentence in the question, indentation of each line inside each condition of `If` is determined by Mathematica notebook automatic formatting rules, and I cannot explain why the particular rules were chosen by Wolfram, Inc.

Comment: So as  @ JasonB  mentioned `if` returns an object ... the basic idea is to alter our 'output' accordingly to get our job done? I am satisfied with the answer but is this a common way of doing? ( I am not a frequent user of Mathematica)

Comment: @rainversion_3  There are several ways to obtain multiple results from `If` and related commands.  Most involve generating a `List` of results.  Column simply formats the `List` nicely.